# Magento - Cancel Order not working

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status, cancel-orders

Hello Magento Experts,

I have a strange issue in one of my Magento1.9.x site. In the admin panel, when I log in and then I click `Sales -> Orders -> Edit` any pending order, I click on cancel, it just refreshed the page and nothing happens.

To debug further, I created a clone of the site, and uploaded it on my server, in that I fixed the cancel order issue and I was able to successfully cancel my order.

So I went on the live site and uploaded the same code there, but on live site, I got an error on clicking cancel button: **Invalid Form key, please refresh the page.**

What I fixed is below :

**In file**: `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php`,

**Before** :

```
public function getCancelUrl()
{
return $this->getUrlSecure('*/*/cancel');
}
```

**After** :

```
public function getCancelUrl()
{
return return $this->getUrl('*/*/cancel');
}
```

Can someone please help me what can be the issue on live site?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done compiplation in live site one's?

Comment: No, as this is Magento1, i dont think compilation needed. Do i really need to do that?

Comment: Yes, Magento1 have compilation option as well, try to do that one's and then check, But Before that take backup of the site.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but i fixed it myself by creating a custom function for Cancel order :)